# Installing digital certificates on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to access a clients https website.The client has provided two digital certificates which are required for accessing the website. The certificate names are BuiltinObjectToken-RSASecurity2048v3.crt and RSAPublicRootCAv1.crt respectively.
My machine is running Ubuntu 10.10. I was able to install the certs on a windows machine by double clicking on each cert file.
What is the procedure for installing the certs on my Ubuntu machine ?.

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is called installing a client certificate. You're right; it's a bit different from setting up a certificate in Apache. For client certs, you import them so that your browser can send them to the websites to verify authentication for access.

Which browser are you trying to use them in? Here is a guide for Firefox:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL#Using%20PKCS#12%20Certificates%20in%20Client%20Applications

Answer (score -1):

Google my friend, an you shall find

Or just click this link
http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Apache2_SSL_in_Ubuntu

If you need more help just tell us

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If i understand correctly,the link you shared talks about setting up ssl in apache.But i dont have apache server running on my machine.All i want is to be able to access the https website.So,do i need to install the certs on my local machine,and if so how ?. Sorry,but im kinda confused..please help. Thank You .

Comment: Sorry, so you need to install an existing cert file, perhaps this helps http://linux.about.com/od/ubusrv_doc/a/ubusg25t14.htm